# Многопоточность Java, параллельная работа 2 потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

Задание: добавить в массив значения и вывести из массива. При этом функцию добавления и вывода реализовать, таким образом, чтобы добавление выполнял 1 поток, освобождал монитор для 2 потока, 2 поток выводил значения из массива, очищал массив и освобождал монитор для 1 потока.Повторить 2 раза.

Я понимаю так: 2 поток для вывода захватывает монитор и засыпает,уступая монитор, пока 1 поток не добавит в него значения. 1 поток захватывает монитор и добавляет в него значения, засыпает и уступает монитор. 2 поток просыпается выводит значения, очищает массив, засыпает.

Проблема:реализация

Вот набросок:

```
 public class Main {
public static void main(String args[])
{

    for(int i = 0; i< 2;i++) {
        Test test = new Test();
        S1 s1 = new S1();
        s1.S1arrayList1 = test.getArrayList1();
        s1.start();
    }
    return;
}
}

class Test {
private ArrayList<String> arrayList1;

public Test()
{
    setArrayList1(new ArrayList<>());
}


public synchronized ArrayList<String> getArrayList1() {
    return arrayList1;
}

public void setArrayList1(ArrayList<String> arrayList1) {
    this.arrayList1 = arrayList1;
}
}

class S1 extends Thread {
public ArrayList S1arrayList1;

@Override
public void run() {
    S2 s2 = new S2();
    s2.S1arrayList2 = S1arrayList1;
    s2.start();
    try {
        AddValue();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
    public synchronized void AddValue() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Система1 добавляю значения");
    //Захватываю монитор и добавляю значения
    S1arrayList1.add("A");
    S1arrayList1.add("B");
    //Сплю пока другой поток не извлечет значения
    while(S1arrayList1.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Cистема1 сплю, жду Систему 2");
        this.wait();
    }
    //Бужу 2 поток
   notify();
}
}

class S2 extends Thread {

public ArrayList S1arrayList2;

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        PrintValue();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    public synchronized void PrintValue() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Система2 вывожу значения");
    //Вывожу значения
    for(int i= 0; i < S1arrayList2.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(S1arrayList2.get(i));
    }
    //Очищаю массив
    S1arrayList2.clear();
    //Бужу другой поток
    notify();
    //Засыпаю
    while (!S1arrayList2.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Система2 сплю, жду Система 1");
        this.wait();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У потоков должен быть *общий* монитор, нестатические `synchronized`-методы используют как монитор `this`, получается потоки вызывают `notify`/`wait` у разных объектов, поэтому и не работает.

[Здесь](http://ideone.com/ev098S) лежит решение с комментариями, но надеюсь написаного выше хватит что бы исправить вашу реализацию. Материалы по теме:
[`Object#wait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--), [`Object#notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--)